# Why does NetLogo not show 'x' values when using nw:load-graphml with a different breed?

Tags: simulation, netlogo, agent-based-modeling, graphml

I'm working on a NetLogo project where I'm using the `nw:load-graphml` function from the NW extension to load data from a GraphML file into my NetLogo model.

When I use `nw:set-context turtles routes` and then call `nw:load-graphml "orbis.graphml"`, my code works perfectly. Here is the code that works:

```
extensions [nw]

directed-link-breed [ routes route ]

routes-own [ days expense km route-type ]

turtles-own [ pots node-id x y modern province rank town-name ]

to setup
  clear-all
  
  nw:set-context turtles routes
  
  nw:load-graphml "orbis.graphml" 
  
  ask turtles [
    
    show x
  
  ]
 
  reset-ticks
end
```

The variable `x` is the x coordinate of a city in a network.

However, when I change the turtle breed to `cities` and use `nw:set-context cities routes` instead, I'm unable to retrieve `x` values from the cities. This is the code that doesn't work:

```
extensions [nw]

breed [ cities city ]

directed-link-breed [ routes route ]

routes-own [ days expense km route-type ]

cities-own [ pots  node-id x y modern province rank town-name ]


to setup
  clear-all
  
  nw:set-context cities routes
  
  nw:load-graphml "orbis.graphml" 
  
  ask cities [
    
    show x
  
  ]
 
  reset-ticks
end
```

Here, when I ask cities to show `x`, I get nothing.

My GraphML file contains nodes with `x` attributes, as shown in this extract:

```
<node id="n0">
  <data key="d0">1</data>
  <data key="d1">50001</data>
  <data key="d2">0</data>
  <data key="d3">Raetia</data>
  <data key="d4">Germany</data>
  <data key="d5">10.909</data>
  <data key="d6">60</data>
  <data key="d7">47.909</data>
  <data key="d8">1</data>
  <data key="d9">Abodiacum</data>
  <data key="d10">0</data>
</node>
```

My project is built on top of [this](https://www.comses.net/codebases/92b5dc6c-a124-4647-91d4-e7365264eac8/releases/1.0.0/) project. Pressing download will get you the `.nlogo` file and the `orbis.graphml` file.

Can someone explain why the `x` values are not showing up for the `cities` breed, while they do for turtles? Why does the breed change cause this issue?

Comment: Would you mind to make your post reproducible? Stack Overflow always encouraged to formulate problems using MCVE-based example, that reproduces the issue. Feel free to go against this Community Netiquette, yet chances of have your problem solved are way lesser than with the reproducible MCVE posted.

Comment: Hi, I included a link to the project I'm using to build my own model. If you press download, you can find the `orbis.graphml` file needed to make the code I shared reproducible. Sorry for not including it in my first post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Netlogo [User Manual for the Nw extension](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/nw.html#nw:load-graphml) mentions the following (emphasis mine):

> The key idea is that `nw:load-graphml` will try to assign the attribute values defined in the GraphML file to NetLogo agent variables of the same names (this is not case sensitive). The first one it tries to set is breed **if it is there**, so the turtle or link will get the right breed and, hence, the right breed variables. The load expects the plural form of the breed for a turtle or link, it will not recognize the singular form.

This means that, if you want to use a particular breed for nodes and edges, then this breed must be defined in the GraphML file.

For the edges the breed is already defined (line 23):

```xml
<key attr.name="BREED" attr.type="string" for="edge" id="d20"/>
```

And each individual edge contains a key that specifies that this edge is part of the breed `routes`:

```xml
<data key="d20">routes</data>
```

For nodes however, no breed is specified in the GraphML file. This means that NetLogo is unable to assign the nodes to the `cities` nodeset. It is however not very difficult to modify the GraphML file to specify the breed for nodes as well. Add the following to the main graph specification:

```xml
<key attr.name="BREED" attr.type="string" for="node" id="dbreed"/>
```

Then add a data key to each node:

```xml
<node id="n0">
      <data key="dbreed">cities</data>
      <data key="d0">1</data>
      <data key="d1">50001</data>
      <data key="d2">0</data>
      <data key="d3">Raetia</data>
      <data key="d4">Germany</data>
      <data key="d5">10.909</data>
      <!-- more data here -->
</node>
```

Now of course you don't want to type the extra line manually for all 678 cities. You can do a regular expression search-and-replace to make this automatic. Replace all occurrences of the following:

```
(<node id="n\d+">)
```

with the matched string followed by a newline, a bit of indentation, and the extra line:

```
\1\n      <data key="dbreed">cities</data>
```

The exact regular expression syntax may differ between text editors, but this is the general idea. Of course you can also do this properly with an XML editor but the regex version seems to work fine.

Result after modifying the GraphML file, with unchanged NetLogo code:

[image]